# Maven archetype fetching old version

Tags: maven

I am generating a maven project using an archetype that I've uploaded to the central repository.

```
mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opencoweb \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=coweb-archetype
```

The latest version is 0.8.3.1, but the version I get instead is 0.8.3. I have cleared out my cache `~/.m2`, and running the above command stil downloads 0.8.3 instead of the latest version. Does anyone know why? Did I forget to specify something when I uploaded/created the 0.8.3.1 module? I uploaded the module earlier this month (Oct 3), and according to http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/opencoweb/coweb-archetype/maven-metadata.xml, the "latest version" is 0.8.3.1.

Edit:
I can download the latest 0.8.3.1 version, but only if I specify `-DarchetypeVersion=0.8.3.1`. However, this is clearly undesirable.

Comment: Maven probably get confused when comparing/resolving latest version between 0.8.3 and 0.8.3.1, try using Maven convention 0.8.3-1 instead of 0.8.3.1 publish your archetype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this answer. maybe the Latest-part is helpful for your needs.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13058666/1602465